# CSS calc() accuracy issue

Tags: html, css

**Plan:**

I would like to have 3 things on a web page to be arranged like this with no gap in between:

[Img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AMbi.png)

They are under the same parent and all 3 of them are 50% width of the parent container.

**Reality:**

I used calc() to calculate padding-bottom based on their respective aspect ratio and the width

3:2 block:

```
width: 50%;
padding-bottom: calc(100% * 2 / 3);
```

15:7 block:

```
width: 50%;
padding-bottom: calc(100% * 7 / 15);
```

5:1 block:

```
width: 50%;
padding-bottom: calc(100% / 5);
```

[Img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRwDA.png)

The result is nearly perfect except the height of the 3:2 block is 409.083px and the sum of height of the other two blocks is 286.35 + 122.717 = 409.067px which is 0.016px shorter. But the math is correct `width*2/3 == width*7/15 + width/5` since all 3 of them have a width of 613.633px.

Because I have more blocks after these 3, this error messed up the whole layout below them.

Is there a way to make calc() give accurate result or is there a better approach to make this type of layout possible? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using grid?

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide a snippet that shows your implementation? It seems to work as expected for me, with the total padding of the second and third block equaling the padding of the first block. See the snippet attached to see my result.

Is your height set to 0? Also, check if you have any margins or borders set as well, since those properties can throw off your alignment.

```css
.wrapper::after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

.block {
 float: left;
 height: 0;
 width: 50%;
}

.block--3-2 {
 padding-bottom: calc(100% * 2 / 3);
 background: blue;
}

.block--15-7 {
 padding-bottom: calc(100% * 7 / 15);
 background: red;
}

.block--5-1 {
 padding-bottom: calc(100% / 5);
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block block--3-2">3-2</div>
  <div class="block block--15-7">15-7</div>
  <div class="block block--5-1">5-1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! My code is pretty much the same idea as your snippet. For your snippet, when I clicked on the "full page" button and change the width of the page to, for example, [961px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGkPa.png), the 3-2 block is 629.98px tall, 15-7 is 441px tall, and 5-1 is 189px tall. There comes the small error 629.98 != 441 + 189.